# Find all uses of a method (including via interface) using NDepend

Tags: c#, ndepend, cqlinq

Using [NDepend](http://www.ndepend.com/), how can I find all, direct and indirect, uses of a specific method or property?

In particular, I need to find usages that occur **via an interface** somewhere along the use path.  Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Right clicking a method anywhere in the UI, and selecting the menu: *Select Method... > ...that are using me (directly or indirectly)* leads to a code query like:

```
from m in Methods 
let depth0 = m.DepthOfIsUsing("NUnit.Core.NUnitFramework+Assert.GetAssertCount()")
where depth0  >= 0 orderby depth0
select new { m, depth0 }
```

The problem is that such query gives indirect usage, but doesn't look for calls that occurs **via an interface** (or an overridden method declared in a base class).

Hopefully what you are asking for can be obtained with this query:

```
// Retrieve the target method by name
let methodTarget = Methods.WithFullName("NUnit.Core.NUnitFramework+Assert.GetAssertCount()").Single()

// Build a ICodeMetric<IMethod,ushort> representing the depth of indirect
// call of the target method.
let indirectCallDepth = 
   methodTarget.ToEnumerable()
   .FillIterative(
       methods => methods.SelectMany(
          m => m.MethodsCallingMe.Union(m.OverriddensBase)))

from m in indirectCallDepth.DefinitionDomain
select new { m, callDepth = indirectCallDepth[m]  }
```

The two corner stones of this query are:

- The call to [FillIterative()](http://www.ndepend.com/API/webframe.html?NDepend.API~NDepend.CodeModel.ExtensionMethodsHelpers~FillIterative.html) to select recursively the indirect call.
- The call to the property [IMethod.OverriddensBase](http://www.ndepend.com/API/webframe.html?NDepend.API~NDepend.CodeModel.IMethod~OverriddensBase.html), as its name suggests. For a method **M** this returns the enumerable of all method declared in a base class or an interface, overriden by **M**.

Comment: Is it possible to generate graph from results of this query? the problem that I get is that usages through overrides are not shown...

Comment: no for now edge on graph only shows "real" dependencies, this situation will evolve